# JMeter - Java.net.URISyntaxException: Illegal character in path at index

Tags: java, jmeter

I'm testing an api in Jmeter

When passing the url in postman I get proper response
[image]

But when use the same in Jmeter I get error
[image]

The path I'm using:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Your request payload contains [characters which are not allowed to be present in URL](https://www.urlencoder.io/learn/) so you need to wrap what you put in "Path" section of the HTTP Request sampler into [__urlencode() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__urlencode)

More information: [Apache JMeter Functions - An Introduction](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-functions-introduction)

Comment: I have figured out the issue that __urlencode is not accpeting curly brackets i.e. {} which are required in the json call